# Javascript - Create intervals of numbers as keys in a map

Tags: javascript

I need to create a map where the keys are ranges of ages, having a minimal age (18 years old), like this:

```
{
    "[18-20]": 5,
    "[21-30]": 3,
    "[31-40]": 10,
    "[41-50]": 90,
    "[51-60]": 10,
    ...
}
```

So, if I have a method "storeAge", and an empty map

```
const ages = {};

function storeAge(age) {
   /*
      Note: Age will always be >= 18
   */

   // some algorithm
}
```

and I call it with the following params:

```
storeAge(19);
```

the "ages" map will be:

```
{
   "[18-20]": 1, // The value is incremented by one when adding age to the interval
}
```

then if I do:

```
storeAge(19);
storeAge(20);
storeAge(21);
```

the resulted object will be:

```
{
   "[18-20]": 3, // 1 (previously, I stored one age) + 2
   "[21-30]": 1, // 0 + 1
}
```

Any ideas? I don't know how to make keys in intervals.

Thank you.

Comment: keys can be strings. 
So you example is correct. 
I am not understanding your issue, issues creating the keys? accessing the keys?

Comment: 18-20 and 20-30..... who gets 20?

Comment: @epascarello the first one, sorry, will update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the interval and increment the count like so:

```js
const ages = {};

function storeAge(age) {
  const start = Math.floor((age - 1) / 10) * 10 + 1,
    end = start + 9,
    intvl = Math.max(start, 18) + "-" + end;
  ages[intvl] = (ages[intvl] || 0) + 1;
}
storeAge(19);
console.log(ages);
storeAge(19);
storeAge(20);
storeAge(21);
console.log(ages);
```

Comment: it is 21-30, not 21-23. I mean, 10 by 10.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to set the  `Map` keys to an array with 2 items, the min & max values of the group. Then when you call `setAge` find the correct group and increment the count by 1. For example:

```js
const ageCountMap = new Map([
  [
    [18, 20], 0
  ],
  [
    [21, 30], 0
  ],
  [
    [31, 40], 0
  ],
  [
    [41, 50], 0
  ],
  [
    [51, 60], 0
  ],
]);

function setAge(age) {
  const ageGroupKey = getMapKeyByAge(age);

  if (ageGroupKey) {
    ageCountMap.set(ageGroupKey, ageCountMap.get(ageGroupKey) + 1);
  }


}

function getMapKeyByAge(age) {
  for (entry of ageCountMap) {
    const [key] = entry;
    const [groupMinAge, groupMaxAge] = key;
    if (groupMinAge <= age && groupMaxAge >= age) {
      return key;
    }
  }

  return null;
}

setAge(19);
setAge(20);
setAge(21);
setAge(22);
setAge(31);
setAge(30);
setAge(45);
setAge(55);

for (entry of ageCountMap) {
  const [key, val] = entry;
  console.dir(`Group ${key} has: ${val} members`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to get the ranges from given age, once you get the range you can set this value inside map.

**Getting Age Range**

```
function getAgeRange(age)
{
var startRange;
if(age<21 && age>17)
{
startRange = 18
}else{
 startRange = age - (age%10) +1
 }
var endRange = age - (age%10) +10
return "[" + startRange + "-" + endRange + "]";
}
```

**Setting ages by calling storeAge method**

```
  const ages =  new Map();       
    function storeAge(age) {
    var range = getAgeRange(age);
    console.log(range);
    if(ages.get(range) == undefined)
    {
    ages.set(range,1);
    }
    else
    {
    ages.set(range,ages.get(1)+1);
    }
    }
```